# Remove dataframe rows without longest list

Tags: python, pandas

My search skills must be failing me because this has to be a common issue.  I have a dataframe with nested lists, and am trying to remove all those that don't have the longest list:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data = [["a", "b", "c", ["d", "e"]],
                          ["a", "b", "c", ["e"]],
                          ["l", "m", "n", ["o"]], 
                  columns = ["c1", "c2", "c3", "c4"])

# max doesn't evaluate length ~ this is wrong
df.groupby(by=["c1", "c2", "c3"])["c4"].apply(max)
c1  c2  c3
a   b   c        [e]
l   m   n        [o]
Name: c4, dtype: object

# but length does ~ but using an int to equate to another row isn't guaranteed
df.groupby(by=["c1", "c2", "c3"])["c4"].apply(len)
c1  c2  c3
a   b   c     2
l   m   n     1
Name: c4, dtype: int64
```

These must be grouped first as each of those three columns make up a unique master key that I need the longest list from.  Each group also has varying length lists, for most its size is 1, for others it can be as high as 5. The end goal should be a new dataframe like this:

```
c1  c2  c3  c4
a   b   c   ["d", "e"]
l   m   n   ["o"]
```

Comment: Not sure on what basis  you are eliminating some rows?

Comment: Those rows which don't have the longest list in column `c4` for each grouping of `c1, c2, c3`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data =[["a", "b", "c", ["d", "e"]],
                         ["a", "b", "c", ["e"]],
                         ["l", "m", "n", ["o"]]],
                  columns = ["c1", "c2", "c3", "c4"])

df['len'] = df['c4'].apply(len)

max_groups = df[df.groupby(['c1', 'c2', 'c3'])['len'].transform(max) == df['len']]
```

We add an extra column corresponding to the length of the list in `c4`, and then filter the dataframe to those records where the length of `c4` is the same as the max length of `c4` for the grouping. This returns `max_groups` as:

```
  c1 c2 c3      c4  len
0  a  b  c  [d, e]    2
2  l  m  n     [o]    1
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't even hit me to just add a new column.  Smooth solution.